# Laravel 5.3 - Merge array based on 2 matching keys?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.3

Given the following two arrays, how can they be merged efficiently to result in the third array?
**productData**

```
$productData =
[
  {
    "product_id": 4,
    "type": "electronic",
    "name": "monitor",
    "specs": {
      "HDMI": true,
      "VGA": false
    }
  },
  {
    "product_id": 5,
    "type": "electronic",
    "name": "HDMI cable",
    "specs": {
      "length": "3ft"
    }
  },
  {
    "product_id": 6,
    "type": "kitchen",
    "name": "spoon"
  }
]
```

**products**

```
$products =
{
  "products": 3,
  "per_page": 10,
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "product_type": "electronic",
      "product_id": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "type": "electronic",
      "product_id": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "type": "kitchen",
      "product_id": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

**productsFinal** (`$productData` merged into `$products` - based on matching combo of `product_id/product_id` and `type/product_type`)

```
$productsFinal = 
{
  "products": 3,
  "per_page": 10,
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "product_type": "electronic",
      "product_id": 6,

      // How to merge product data and wrap with "data" key
      "data": {
        "product_id": 6,
        "type": "kitchen",
        "name": "spoon"
      }

    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "type": "electronic",
      "product_id": 5,

      // How to merge product data and wrap in "data" key
      "data": {
        "product_id": 5,
        "type": "electronic",
        "name": "HDMI cable",
        "specs": {
          "length": "3ft"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "type": "kitchen",
      "product_id": 4,

      // How to merge product data and wrap in "data" key
      "data": {
        "product_id": 6,
        "type": "kitchen",
        "name": "spoon"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried different things for the outcome in a foreach loop but still cannot get it to render as intended:

```
foreach($productData as $productDataItem) {
  // when $productDataItem.product_id == $product.product_id && $productDataItem.type == $product.product_type
  // move the matching $productDataItem object into matching $product object, wrapped in a new "data" key
}
```

Comment: This is not PHP code here. What have you tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: It is in PHP (Laravel) where I have this issue, that is what a laravel collection outputs. I tried a few different ways, but wasn't able to accomplish the format of the third array, and it is taking me way too long to implement. That's why I posted the question under `php/laravel`, as someone who knows laravel may know how to do this.

Comment: Are you trying to make a JSON response for an API? If yes, I may have a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Laravel too well. However you can join your data objects quite easily:

```
<?php
$productData = json_decode('[
  {
    "product_id": 4,
    "type": "electronic",
    "name": "monitor",
    "specs": {
      "HDMI": true,
      "VGA": false
    }
  },
  {
    "product_id": 5,
    "type": "electronic",
    "name": "HDMI cable",
    "specs": {
      "length": "3ft"
    }
  },
  {
    "product_id": 6,
    "type": "kitchen",
    "name": "spoon"
  }
]');

$products = json_decode('{
  "products": 3,
  "per_page": 10,
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "type": "electronic",
      "product_id": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "type": "electronic",
      "product_id": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "type": "kitchen",
      "product_id": 4
    }
  ]
}');

// combine both data objects 

foreach($products->data As &$p) {
    foreach($productData As $d) {
        if(property_exists($p, "product_id") && property_exists($d, "product_id") && property_exists($p, "type") && property_exists($d, "type")) {
            if($p->product_id==$d->product_id && $p->type==$d->type) {
                //$p = (object) array_merge((array) $p, (array) $d);
                $p->data = $d; // updated answer
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo("<pre>");
echo json_encode($products, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


?>
```

You can test the code here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/98a50c35ee32c30f0d2be1661f7afb5895174cbe
Update: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aeebfdcf4f4db5e960260e931982570cfed19e0e

Comment: Thank you for this, it is really close to the final output, but I really am trying to get the exact syntax in `$productsFinal` (my final output), outputted from your sandbox to match the final output. Currently there are 2 differences, the `"data": [` and the fact that it adds the index to each product. Any idea how to change your logic to match `$productsFinal`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check this package [dingo/api](https://github.com/dingo/api). I assume you want to display some kind of JSON response. Take a look at [Transformers](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Transformers). You can do something like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Transformers;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductData;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class ProductsDataTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    /**
     * Turn this item object into a generic array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function transform(ProductData $productdata)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $productdata->id,
            'product_type' => $productdata->product_type,
            'product /*or data*/' => Product::find($productdata->product_id),
        ];
    }

}
```

This would find the product by it's ID and look like this :

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "product_type": "electronic",
  "product" {
    "product_id": 6,
    "type": "kitchen",
    "name": "spoon"
  },
},
```

You can then also create a transformer for Product to take care of your specs attribute to do the same thing.